# How would I know data and annot have same shape or not using seaborn commands in python?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to draw a heatmap using python's seaborn library for the first time and
I get the following error:

```
                   ValueError: `data` and `annot` must have same shape
```

for the following command i guess:

```
sns.heatmap(result,annot=labels,fmt="",cmap='RdYlGn',linewidths=0.30,ax=ax)
```

I have tried searching for my error but haven't found anyone sharing my problem.
I would be more than glad if anyone could help me.

My result shape is 122,127 and my labels shape is 129,120
Now shouldn't they have the same shape as I intended?

A short part of my code:

```
       gene_id=((np.asarray(df['gene_id'])).reshape(129,120))
    
       fold_change=((np.asarray(df['fold_change'])).reshape(129,120))
    
       result=df.pivot(index='Yrows',columns='Xcols',values='fold_change')
       labels = (np.asarray(["{0} \n {1:.2f}".format(symb,value)
                             for symb, value in zip(gene_id.flatten(),
                                                      fold_change.flatten())])
                ).reshape(129,120)
```

My results are foldchange values and my labels are gene_ids.

Comment: Could you please add the sample of your data and your labels, and, as mentioned in the error, check their shapes (try `result.shape` and `labels.shape`)

Comment: most likely something went wrong in your pivot

Answer (score 2):

So I just marked annot with  the "True"- like this:

sns.heatmap(corr,**annot = True,** linewidths=0.2, fmt=".2f")